Expo Router Link - Type '"/sign-in"' is not assignable to type 'Href<string | object>'.ts
I have an expo project, and setting up a clerk auth. I have followed all the required code clerk gave, and now getting this error on the links. Everything looks okay to me, but I cant figure out how to solve this issue.
with this folder structure:

The Error:
Type '"/sign-in"' is not assignable to type 'Href<string | object>'.ts(2322)
Link.d.ts(55, 5): The expected type comes from property 'href' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkProps<string | object> & { children?: ReactNode; }'
(property) LinkProps<string | object>.href: Href<string | object>
Path to route to.


app/_layout.tsx
import FontAwesome from '@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { DarkTheme, DefaultTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import { Stack, Slot } from 'expo-router';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import 'react-native-reanimated';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/components/useColorScheme';

import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store'
import { ClerkProvider, ClerkLoaded } from '@clerk/clerk-expo'

const tokenCache = {
  async getToken(key: string) {
    try {
      const item = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key)
      if (item) {
        console.log(`${key} was used  \n`)
      } else {
        console.log('No values stored under key: ' + key)
      }
      return item
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('SecureStore get item error: ', error)
      await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(key)
      return null
    }
  },
  async saveToken(key: string, value: string) {
    try {
      return SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value)
    } catch (err) {
      return
    }
  },
}

const publishableKey = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY!

if (!publishableKey) {
  throw new Error(
    'Missing Publishable Key. Please set EXPO_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY in your .env',
  )
}

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from 'expo-router';

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: '',
};

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require('../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
    ...FontAwesome.font,
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return <RootLayoutNav />;
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <ClerkProvider tokenCache={tokenCache} publishableKey={publishableKey}>
    <ClerkLoaded>    
        <Slot />
    </ClerkLoaded>
  </ClerkProvider>
  );
}


app/(auth)/_layout.tsx
import { Redirect, Stack } from 'expo-router'
import { useAuth } from '@clerk/clerk-expo'

export default function AuthRoutesLayout() {
  const { isSignedIn } = useAuth()

  if (isSignedIn) {
    return <Redirect href={'/'} />
  }

  return <Stack />
}

app/(home)/index.tsx
this is where the error originates the error is on the href of Link.
import { SignedIn, SignedOut, useUser } from '@clerk/clerk-expo'
import { Link } from 'expo-router'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'

export default function Page() {
  const { user } = useUser()

  return (
    <View>
      <SignedIn>
        <Text>Hello {user?.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress}</Text>
      </SignedIn>
      <SignedOut>
        <Link href="/sign-in">
          <Text>Sign In</Text>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/sign-up">
          <Text>Sign Up</Text>
        </Link>
      </SignedOut>
    </View>
  )
}


try to modify the href values like this
`

Sign In

Sign Up
`
doesnt work. I found this, (https://docs.expo.dev/router/reference/typed-routes/)
It says that relative paths are not supported, but when I added "./sign-in" the error went away

Looks like it is a type issue where the generic type definition of the LinkComponent was put on the wrong side of the curly brackets https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/packages/expo-router/src/link/Link.tsx#L92C1-L96C2. Updating the following in the Link.d.ts file in the node_modules seems to fix it. Will look into creating an issue in the repo for it as well.
    export interface LinkComponent {
  <T extends string | object>(props: React.PropsWithChildren<LinkProps<T>>): JSX.Element;
  /** Helper method to resolve an Href object into a string. */
  resolveHref: (href: Href) => string;
}

To
export interface LinkComponent<T extends string | object> {
    (props: React.PropsWithChildren<LinkProps<T>>): JSX.Element;
    /** Helper method to resolve an Href object into a string. */
    resolveHref: (href: Href) => string;
}


My error also disappeared when I added a "." even though the docs say not to.

As a workaround solution I made a constant as follows and used that as the route path.
import {Href} from 'expo-router'

const MY_ROUTE = "/my/route" as Href

<Link <Link href={MY_ROUTE}>

Specially we can use the same method even without making a constant, when we use functions like router.navigate() or route.replace()
router.replace("/my/route" as Href)

